# Integrating opbeat with sails

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to integrate [opbeat](http://opbeat.com/) with sails.js. They have a node.js [client](https://github.com/opbeat/opbeat-node) which includes middleware support for Connect and Express.
I've tried to create a custom middleware in `http.js`

```
module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

    opbeat : require('opbeat')({
        organizationId: '...',
        appId: '...',
        secretToken: '...'
    }),

    order: [
      'opbeat',
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],

  }
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. If you could please help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Cyberon: You should not publish your secret token on the internetz

Comment: @ThomasWatson Oops. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned from the initializer function isn't a proper middleware function (it's just an Opbeat client). To get the middleware function, call `middleware.connect()` on the client:

```
var opbeat = require('opbeat')({
  organizationId: '...',
  appId: '...',
  secretToken: '...'
})

module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    opbeat: opbeat.middleware.connect(), // get the Opbeat middleware function

    order: [
      ... // put the bulk of your middleware here
      'opbeat'
    ]
  }
}
```

P.S. The function is called `middleware.connect()` because it was the [connect module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) that set the standard of having a middleware function that expects the 3 arguments; Request, Response and Callback. An alias exists that is called `middleware.express()` - but it's just that: An alias.

**Update:**

I reversed the order of the middleware in the example above so that Opbeat is placed at the end. This is important to that that it can catch errors tickling down the middleware-chain.